# Search inside Array for Value on a MYSQL Output

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

The code below doesn't seem to work or find anything on an array. I'm using "in_array" to search for the needle in the stack. I also tried exploding the contents with comma separated and won't work. Any suggestions? Also I tried "array_search".

```
$q4 = "SELECT domain_name,slots_config.bid FROM slots_pid,slots_config,slots_sites 
WHERE slots_config.bid=slots_pid.bid && slots_sites.aid=slots_pid.aid";
$result4 = mysql_query($q4);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
{
    $resultarray[] = $row;
}


if (in_array("test",$resultarray))
  {
  echo "Match found";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Match not found";
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`in_array()` won't work with that sort of array, because it's multi-dimensional.

Your array looks like this:

```
$resultarray[0]['domain_name'] = 'first row domain name';
$resultarray[0]['bid'] = 'first row bid';
$resultarray[1]['domain_name'] = 'second row domain name';
...
```

You can't use `in_array()` to search in that, so you'll have to do it with another method, something like looping over the array, or building `$resultarray` differently.

Similarly, `array_search()` doesn't work on multidimensional arrays, so you could do something like looping over the first dimension and `array_search()`-ing each second dimension.

Let me know if you want more detail.

Comment: Hey can I have more detail please i also think this will be a solution to this problem.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539649/php-how-to-check-2-statements-to-only-send-one-message-no-duplicates-between/14539663#14539663

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you have here is an 'array of arrays'. That is, in your while() loop, $row is an array which corresponds to the data from your mysql query. So each element of $resultarray actually contains an array, rather than a string.

Try doing this: `print_r($resultarray)`. This will display the entire structure of $resultarray, and you can see how you're creating an array-of-arrays.

To use in_array, you woul need to do something akin to `in_array("test", $resultarray[0])`

Comment: print_r, var_dump are your friends. Understanding your data is faster than trying all the different php functions one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$q4 = "SELECT domain_name,slots_config.bid FROM slots_pid,slots_config,slots_sites 
WHERE slots_config.bid=slots_pid.bid && slots_sites.aid=slots_pid.aid";
$result4 = mysql_query($q4);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
{
  if (in_array("test",$row))
  {
     echo "Match found";
  }
  else
  {
     echo "Match not found";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are having is that it in_array only searches the first dimension of your two dimensional array.  I also don't understand why you're loading the whole result into an array before you search (but perhaps that's useful elsewhere in your program).

Try:

```
 $found = false;
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4))
 {
    if (in_array($needle, $row){
      print "here it is";
      $found = true;
      break;
 }

 if (!$found) {
      print "not found";
 }
```