# PHP how to check 2 statements to only send one message no duplicates between

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to code a notification system for a profile wall script I made a long time ago for a forum.
The trouble I have is, that I am trying to only send one PM to the people who fit the criteria for the PM, but I also have 2 select statements in MYSQL to find the people who should be PM'd.

I have 2 tables to select from... `log_statuses` and `log_status_replies`
I am trying to achieve this.
I want it to notify everyone who has commented only ONCE! Also the persons wall it belongs to and the person who written the status on the persons wall, but not yourself if you written it.
Kinda complex that's why I am struggling to get this right...

Here is my code for it to search through who commented and send them a PM.
How would I also do the checks for who written the status and who's wall it is, without it sending a duplicate PM if they have commented aswell.

Otherwise they would receive a PM because they have commented and because its their status/wall.
I hope you understand that, kinda hard to explain.

Here is my source code.. I would love anyone who could help..

```
$query = $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
    SELECT id_member, id_poster
    FROM {db_prefix}log_statuses
    WHERE id_status = {int:id_status}',
    array(
        'id_status' => $status,
    )
);
   list($id_member,$id_poster) = $smcFunc['db_fetch_row']($query);


if ($id_poster != $ucomment || $id_member != $ucomment)
{   

    $query2 = $smcFunc['db_query']('', '
        SELECT DISTINCT id_member
        FROM {db_prefix}log_status_replies
        WHERE id_status = {int:id_status}',
        array(
            'id_status' => $status,
        )
    );

    while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($query2)) {
        if ($row['id_member'] != $ucomment)
        {
            $pm_recipients = array(
                'to' => array($row['id_member']),
                'bcc' => array(),
            );

            require_once($sourcedir . '/Subs-Post.php');

            $notify_body = $txt['status_body'] . '[iurl]' .$scripturl . '?action=profile;area=showstatus;s=' . $status . '[/iurl]';
            $notify_body = str_replace("%poster",$context['user']['name'],$notify_body);

            $pm_from = array(
                        'id' => $ucomment,
                        'username' => '',
                        'name' => '',
                    );

            sendpm($pm_recipients,$txt['status_subject'] , $notify_body,false,$pm_from);
        }       
    }           
}
```

$id_member is the persons wall, $id_poster is the person who posted on the wall.
$ucomment is the person who is posting..

Comment: Hmm I can question this in a different way.
How would I do a while on the sql select statement and check that this person isn't the poster/wall owner from the previous mysql select statement?
So that they can both be checked to make sure it doesn't PM them twice if they show up in both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. I built an array from the while, then checked if the value exists from the comments table when checking the other table to see who to PM also..

```
    $id_comment = array();
            while ($row = $smcFunc['db_fetch_assoc']($query2)) {
            $id_comment[] = $row['id_member'];
    }

if (!in_array($id_poster, $id_comment) && !in_array($id_member, $id_comment)) {
     //Send PM
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `UNION`:

For example::

```
Select column1 from table1 where condition1=true
UNION
Select column1 from table1 where condition2=true
```

The resultset will not have a duplicate records.

By Chance, if you need all the values including the duplicates use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Sorry i don't understand how I would apply that to my code, as you see I have to check 2 tables... and do a while statement on 1 of them.
The 1st table I check only selects one.